# Dress' construction and Serre spectral sequence

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

Currently, I am reading Serre spectral sequence, given below, using Dress' construction.

> Let $f:E\to B$ be a Serre fibration. Then, there is a first quadrant
>   spectral sequence $\big\{E^r,d^r\}_{r\geq1}$, called the Serre
>   spectral sequence, with the second page
>   $E^2_{p,q}=H_p\big(B;\underline{H_q(F)}\big):$ the singular homology
>   with coefficients in the local system induced by the fibres of $f$.
>   The spectral sequence converges to the singular homology of the
>   topological space $E$ : $$E^2_{p,q}=H_q\big(B;
> \underline{H_q(F)}\big)\underset{p}{\implies} H_{p+q}(E).$$

One of the great things is that it gives a quick proof general Hurewicz Isomorphism Theorem. But the dress construction is based on following fact

> If $f:X\to Y$ is a weak homotopy equivalence, then for any $n\geq 0$
>   the induced map $f_*: H_n(X) \to H_n(Y)$ is an isomorphism.

and which in turn depends on the relative version of the general Hurewicz Isomorphism Theorem. So, some kind of cyclic arguments.

My question is that is there any proof of the above fact without using the Hurewicz Isomorphism Theorem. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe proposition 2.1 in [this note](http://uregina.ca/~franklam/Math527/Math527_0325.pdf) can help you.